# HTML line break within flash error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a flash[:error] with an html line break. When it gets displayed, it literally show `<br />` instead of interpreting it as html and breaking. Heres my error:

```
  flash[:error] = "Format of search criteria is wrong.<br />Should be [
IXLSpecClass value][year]-[Message ID] for example GP07-8"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup. Since strings in Rails 3 (you're in Rails 3, right?) are escaped by default, you'd need to go into your template and instead of `flash[:error]` you would need to print `flash[:error].html_safe` in order to have it avoid automatic escaping.

Comment: Ok so heres the code that displays flash messages: `<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
                        <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" %>
                <% end %>`

Comment: If i chage it to `id => "flash_#{name}.html_safe" %>` it doesnt do anything

Comment: Glad you got it worked out :) Bear in mind, though that there are security risks attached to this: if you *ever* interpolate something unsafe into a flash message, it'll come out unescaped unless you do escaping in the controller, which is complicated. So think carefully before sticking with this solution.

Comment: @Matchu, glad you added that caveat. I was troubleshooting this issue, and after reading your comment decided bolding my user's name in a flash message wasn't so important as to justify this extra security risk.

Answer (score 0):

That is because if you view the source it probably looks like this:

<br /> or to put it simply:  `&lt;br /&gt;`

This is because the html was probably escaped at some point down the line.